# Calling an action within controller in Ember

Tags: ember.js

I am getting some data from server and in my controller I am trying to display that in list format. What I want to do is to allow the user to click on any item of that list and call an action behind it. Here is my js code.

```
            for(var index in posts) {
                if (posts.hasOwnProperty(index)) {
                    console.log(1);
                    var attr = posts[index];
                    //console.log(attr);
                    /*$("ul#previous_recipients").append('<li class="list-group-item"><label>'+attr.name+'' +
                        '</label><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="close g-green" {{action "aa"}}>Add</a></li>');*/

                    $("ul#previous_recipients").append(Ember.Handlebars.compile('<li class="list-group-item"><label>{{attr.name}} </label><a href="#" {{action "test"}}  class=" close g-green">Add</a></li>'));
                }
            }
```

How to call action on it? {{action "test"}} is not being called.

Answer (score 0):

You have to compile the handlebars template and define the test action inside actions hash in the same controller.

`$("ul#previous_recipients").append(Ember.Handlebars.compile('
    <li class="list-group-item"><label>{{attr.name}} </label>
    <a href="#" {{action "test"}}  class=" close g-green">Add</a></li>
'));`

You have to move this html code from controller to a handlebars file,that will be good.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is create an ember view and give it a

```
templateName
```

property which will contain your html and handlebars expression. Alternately, you could, inside the view say

```
defaultTemplate: Em.Handlebars.compile(/*your handlebars and html markup here*/)
```

using Jquery to do things like this is not the ember way of doing things.

Comment: Isn't there a way to do this with jquery?